# Why is \active defined as \char13 (and not 13)?

Tags: active-characters

In plain TeX, we have

```
\chardef\active=13
\catcode`\~=\active
```

I thought a catcode should be assigned a number between 0 and 15, but \active is `\char13`. So how does it work?

Would `` \catcode`\~=13 `` also work?

Comment: @Gradient you see the same in many places eg `\newbox\foo` (or the latex `\newsavebox{\foo}` then `\foo` is defined by `\chardef` (or sometimes `\mathchardef` in lualatex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I learned something new. My prior comment (which I have now removed) referred to changing catcode within a document, not plain TeX sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three issues here, two about performance and one about 'safety'. A `\chardef`'d token is parsed slightly faster than TeX looking for the end of a number, so `\active` is a little better in that regard than an explicit `13`. Today this is not so much of an issue, but was in the past.  Similarly, `\active` is a single token in terms of memory, whereas `13` is two tokens: there's a saving in using the former. Once again,, memory usage today isn't a big problem but was in the past.

Perhaps more important is the rule that TeX keeps looking for the end of a number when digits are given explicitly, whereas for a `\chardef` token this doesn't happen. So for example

```
\catcode`\a=134
```

gives an error but

```
\catcode`\a=\active4
```

isn't. In an explicit use that's not likely to be an issue but if we

```
\def\foo{\catcode`\a=\active}
```

then `\foo 4` is OK, whereas for an explicit `13` we need a space or `\relax` (so yet another token).

(TeX is 'looking for a number' in this context so a `\chardef` or `\mathchardef` token is fine in place of an explicit run of digits. Making `\active` a macro expanding to `13` has the some of the same issues as an explicit value.)

Comment: I found in the TeXbook, page 271: "When a
<chardef token> or <mathchardef token> is used as an internal integer, it denotes the
value in the \chardef or \mathchardef itself." This explains why `\active` used in catcode assigment is like 13 and not `\char13`.